# Criar Lista em c#

Tags: c#

Olá, queria criar uma lista que eu guardar-se strings e chamar elas com valores aleatórios

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class Program{
    static void Main(string[] args) {

      Random rnd = new Random();
      int numero = rnd.Next();
       List<string> list = new List<string>();
       list.Add("Chile");
       list.Add("Brasil");
       list.Add("Argentina");
       List<string> list2 = list.FindAll(x => x.Length == numero);
        Console.Write(list2);
    }
}
```

Só que ele não imprime com valor em aleatório

Answer (score 0):

Você quer pegar um valor aleatório da lista 1?

Se a list2 vai receber apenas um elemento, é muito mais prático você apenas declarar ela como uma **string** no lugar de **list**... *(a não ser que sua ideia realmente seja embaralhar a **list1** na **list2**)*

Pode fazer assim:

```cs
// Pegar um elemento aleatório da lista 1 e jogar na var list2
Random rnd = new Random();

List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("Chile");
list.Add("Brasil");
list.Add("Argentina");

string list2;

int index = rnd.Next(list.Count);
list2 = list[index];

Console.Write(list2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Existem alguns erros no seu código.

O primeiro é que você não trata se o número gerado é maior que o tamanho da lista, isso pode da uma exceção de `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` pois poderá ocorrer casos em que o número gerado é maior que o tamanho da sua lista - 1. Utilizar o operador de módulo `%` pode ajudar neste caso

O segundo erro é que você não precisa fazer um `FindAll` na lista pois ele não seria performático porque ele irá percorrer toda a lista de forma desnecessária.

Por fim, para imprimir o valor bastaria você passar o valor randônico gerado como índice da sua lista da seguinte forma:

```cs
Console.Write(list[numero]);
```